# Buscar dentro de um _POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

Eu queria saber se tem como eu buscar dados dentro de um POST? Eu preciso muito, pois cada box é um id diferente. Exemplo:

```
    **JS:** 
data {'id':id, 'ponto1':ponto1}
    **AJAX:**
id: $id = isset($_GET['id']);
$ponto = isset($_POST['ponto".$id."']);
```

Comment: essa pergunta não faz sentido

Comment: Faz sim, por favor faz um esforço em me ajudar.

Comment: como assim buscar dados dentro de um post? exemplifica isso

Comment: No ajax quando você vai postar, tem o que busca dados de outra página pelo js certo? no caso é o id e o ponto. Porém na página, cada input com name="ponto" tem um id, ex: name="ponto1", name="ponto2" eu queria que fosse assim no ponto post no ajax, para poder buscar qual tipo de ponto é.

Comment: Desculpa mas o teu exemplo não faz sentido, reformula a tua pergunta com exmplos de dados que queres enviar e pegar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que tu podes fazer é passar assim (vou mostrar o input em HTML para entenderes)

Ja que cada ponto tem um id podes fazer assim:

crias um hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="Aqui colocas o teu id"/>

<input type="text" name="post[ID Aqui tm]" />
```

no php pegas assim:

```
$ArrayComId = $_POST['id[]'];

$ArrayComPost = $_POST['Post[]'];
```

depois e so fazeres um foreach e pegares o post de cada ID

```
foreach($arraycomid as $key => $value)
{
  echo $arraycompost[$value];
}
```

É possivel ter algum erro mas a logica é +/- esta

Comment: Agora so precisas fazer um Ajax request ao teu php com os dados no body

Comment: DEU CERTO!!!! Obrigado mesmo!!!